# How to place an element north of another element

Tags: html, css

I have a canvas and two input boxes. I want the layout to match that of the picture, and I want them to stay in place on resize. The canvas is centered on the screen. I used jquery to achieve the effect in the picture, but everything moves incorrectly on resize. I'm sure there is an easier way to do this, any ideas?

[image]

CSS:

```
#userAndPass {
    border:solid 1px #333;
    width:150px;
    height:28px;
    position:absolute;
}

#viewport {
    border:solid 1px #333;
    height : 700px;
    margin: auto;
    left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;
    position: absolute;
    width : 1000px;
    z-index:100;
}
```

JQuery:

```
    var offset = $('#viewport').offset();
    var user = $('#user');

    $('#user').offset({top: (offset.top - 27), left:offset.left});
    $('#pass').offset({top: (offset.top - 27), left:offset.left+160});
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <input id="user" class="userAndPass" type="text" placeholder="username"></input>
    <input id="pass" class="userAndPass" type="password" placeholder="password"></input>        
    <canvas id="viewport"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: North. hmm the title is new… how about the HTML? are we supposed to guess the elements corresponding to those `id`'s?

Comment: I say north because above/top meant "in the way of" on other posts.

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Comment: @Tilwin It was pretty obvious what the id's belonged to.

Comment: @Colton  in most of the cases, reason why the code posted here by users doesn't work is also *obvious*. We're coding, guessing is bad - knowing is good.

Comment: @TilwinJoy : *title* definitely sounds like coming from *Game of Thrones*!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always avoid `position` attribute unless its the last resort....later it always conflicts if you have too much of css :)

Wrap all of your DOM into a parent class (`leftBound`) and align content in it to left.

[**Demo fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/djQt7/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="leftBound">
    <input id="user" class="userAndPass" type="text" placeholder="username"></input>
    <input id="pass" class="userAndPass" type="password" placeholder="password"></input>
    <br /> <!-- to push canvas below input boxes -->
    <canvas id="viewport">canvas in red border</canvas>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.leftBound, input {
    text-align:left;
    border:1px solid grey;
    display : inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap; /* if you dont want to wrap it to new line*/
    vertical-align:top; /* push input boxes to top*/
}
#userAndPass {
    border:solid 1px #333; /*for demo only */
    width:150px;
    height:28px;
}
#viewport {
    border:solid 1px #333;
    height : 700px;
    margin: auto;
    width : 1000px;
    border:1px solid red; /*for demo only */
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had to add `text-align:center` to the body element to center everything and I was good to go.